# Find the # of days since the first case

Tags: r, economics

```
 Example:   
    FIPS       Date     Counts 
    1001       Jan_22    0
    1003       Jan_22    1
    1004       Jan_22    0
    1001       Jan_23    1
    1003       Jan_23    5
    1004       Jan_23    0
    1001       Jan_24    6
    1003       Jan_24    10
    1004       Jan_24    1 
    1001       Jan_25    8
    1003       Jan_25    12
    1004       Jan_25    3
    1001       April_1   20
    1003       April_1   60
    1004.      April_1   50
    
Result:
        FIPS   Date    Counts  DaysSinceFirst
        1001   Jan_23   1      98
        1003   Jan_22   1      99
        1004   Jan_24   1      97
```

I am trying to find the number of days since the 1st case of Covid-19 within different counties in the United States. I need to find the first occurrence of 1 case confirmed in that county and then get R to tell me for each FIPS code is on which date was it that there the first day it was confirmed for 1 case. I am doing all 3141 counties. The dates go from Jan_22 to April_30.

I used

```
 data_long %>%
  filter(Counts > 0) %>%
  group_by(FIPS) %>%
  slice(1L)
```

to get

```
FIPS   Date    Counts  
 1001   Jan_23   1      
 1003   Jan_22   1      
 1004   Jan_24   1
```

But I still need the amount of days from first time there is a confirmed case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the difference between each date and 30 April and then apply rest of the code.

```
library(dplyr)

last_date <- as.Date('2020-04-30')

df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(paste(Date, 2020,sep = '_')), 
         DaysSinceFirst = as.numeric(last_date - Date)) %>%
         #If the last date needs to be taken from the data.
         #DaysSinceFirst = as.numeric(max(last_date) - Date)) %>%
  filter(Counts > 0) %>%
  group_by(FIPS) %>%
  slice(1L)

#   FIPS Date       Counts DaysSinceFirst
#  <int> <date>      <int>          <dbl>
#1  1001 2020-01-23      1             98
#2  1003 2020-01-22      1             99
#3  1004 2020-01-24      1             97
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(date = paste('2020',Date, sep = '_')) %>%  filter(Counts > 0) %>% 
mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date)) %>% arrange(FIPS,date) %>% group_by(FIPS) %>% filter(row_number() == 1) %>% 
mutate(DaysSinceFirst = difftime(lubridate::ymd('2020-04-30'), date, units = 'days'))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   FIPS [3]
   FIPS Date   Counts date       DaysSinceFirst
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <date>     <drtn>        
1  1001 Jan_23      1 2020-01-23 98 days       
2  1003 Jan_22      1 2020-01-22 99 days       
3  1004 Jan_24      1 2020-01-24 97 days
```